# Python regex get address without zip code

Tags: python, regex

I want to get only address without the zipcode

Now, my method will get `'Taiwan,XX Street XX Road,'` and the `123` is excluded.

How can I only exclude the zipcode (`802` or `80233`)

The zip code is made up by 3~5 numbers

```
add1 = '802Taiwan,XX Street XX Road,123'
add2 = '80233Taiwan,XX Street XX Road,123'
result = re.findall(r'[\D]', add1)
result = re.findall(r'[\D]', add2)
```

Comment: is always zipcode present at the first?

Comment: yes,always first in Taiwan

Comment: Are there multiple addresses in a single string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
>>> add1 = '802Taiwan,XX Street XX Road,123'
>>> re.findall(r'^\d+(.*,)\d+$', add1)
['Taiwan,XX Street XX Road,']
```

OR

```
>>> re.findall(r'^(?:802|80233)(.*,)\d+$', add1)
['Taiwan,XX Street XX Road,']
```

Comment: or `re.findall(r'^\d{3,5}(.*),\d+$', add1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply by using native functions.No need of `re` here.

```
x="0233Taiwan,XX Street XX Road,123"
x=x.lstrip("0123456789").rstrip("0123456789")
```

Use `lstrip` and `rstrip`

Comment: @user2492364 try this as well

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex is `\D`, which is excluding all numbers, including the one at the end. This should work -

```
In [4]: re.findall(r'^\d+(.*)$', add1)
Out[4]: ['Taiwan,XX Street XX Road,123']

In [5]: re.findall(r'^\d+(.*)$', add2)
Out[5]: ['Taiwan,XX Street XX Road,123']
```

A modification of your solution would be -

```
In [7]: re.findall(r'\D+\d+$', add1)
Out[7]: ['Taiwan,XX Street XX Road,123']

In [8]: re.findall(r'\D+\d+$', add2)
Out[8]: ['Taiwan,XX Street XX Road,123']
```

This is allowing for digits at the end. However, this solution is fragile, because I'm guessing that the `XX` are also going to be digits. The first solution `r'^\d+(.*)$'` ensures that only digits at the beginning (zip code) are being ignored.